# SSH connection between Amazon MWAA and ec2 instance

Tags: python, shell, airflow, airflow-scheduler, mwaa

I'm trying out the new Amazon MWAA service, my dag ssh into ec2 instance and run a shell script. I'm not sure how to set up the ssh connection between Amazon MWAA environment and ec2 instance.

Currently in our production, the ssh key of prod airflow env are stored under the authorised key directory of remote ec2 instance. When the DAG runs, the script creates the ssh connection in airflow and executes the script.

How to create a ssh connection in Amazon MWAA environment?

Comment: I have a similar issue -I want to run a shell script from my ec-2 instance .So how do I set the path in my DAG to access it?

Comment: I have a similar issue.I have shell scripts written which run from ec-2 instance

Comment: Did you managed to fix it? if so how?

Comment: I fixed it by adding the Elastic IP of MWAA's vpc to the security group of the EC2 instance.

Comment: @Anandraj I am running public  MWAA and ec2 instance in the private subnets and I am not able to SSH from the MWAA into the ec2 instance even after adding VPC elastic IPs it still doesnt work